# Equivalent measures on algebra also equivalent on $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite positive measures on a measurable space  $(X,\mathcal A)$. Let $\mathcal G$ be an algebra of $\mathcal A$. If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are equivalent on $\mathcal G$ in the sense that $ \mu(A)=0$ if and only if $\nu(A)=0$ for all $A\in \mathcal G$, can we conclude that they are equivalent on $\sigma(\mathcal G)$ as well, where $\sigma(\mathcal G)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal G$? If not, is there any counter example?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No. Generating algebras can be quite small. e.g. finite unions of $[a,b)$ in $[0,1)$. It's quite easy to come up with two measures that give positive measure to all open sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Let $X$ be the unit interval $(0,1]$ with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$.  Let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure.  Enumerate the rationals in $(0,1]$ as $\{q_n\}$ and let $\nu$ be a measure assigning mass $2^{-n}$ to the point $q_n$.  Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the algebra of all finite union of half-open intervals $(a,b]$, which generates $\mathcal{A}$.  Then $\mu$ and $\nu$ both assign nonzero measure to every set in $\mathcal{G}$, but are mutually singular on $\mathcal{A}$.

(I was already typing this before Anthony Quas commented!)